# Where is the positive half-space of this determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

With reference to the figure below, the determinant $[a,b,c,d]$ should be positive according to a right-hand rule for planes, but when I calculate the determinant for various points, I get the wrong sign. The way I've interpreted this right-hand rule, is to point my right-hand fingers from a to b, then bend the fingers towards c, and my thumb points to the positive half-space. What is wrong with this?

Given four three-dimensional points $a=(a_x,a_y,a_z),b=(b_x,b_y,b_z),c=(c_x,c_y,c_z),d=(d_x,d_y,d_z)$, the determinant is defined as:

\begin{equation}\begin{bmatrix}a,b,c,d\end{bmatrix} := \begin{vmatrix}a_x&a_y&a_z&1\\b_x&b_y&b_z&1\\c_x&c_y&c_z&1\\d_x&d_y&d_z&1\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} = \begin{vmatrix}a_x-d_x&a_y-d_y&a_z-d_z\\b_x-d_x&b_y-d_y&b_z-d_z\\c_x-d_x&c_y-d_y&c_z-d_z\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

[image]

Comment: I haven't checked your algrbra from going from a $4 \times 4$ determinant to the $3 \times 3$ determinant but are you sure you have correctly expanded using the cofactors for each $(i, j)$ entry?

Answer (score 1):

When considering that the determinant should equal $\vec{ad}\cdot (\vec{ab} \times \vec{ac})$, it becomes clear which half space is the positive one, using the standard vector cross-product right-hand rule.

Solving both the determinant and the triple product show that the right-hand rule or the determinant was incorrectly defined and yields the wrong sign.

Answer (score 0):

The vectors in the drawing are $b-a,$ $c-a$ and $d-a.$ The corresponds to the subtraction of the first row from the other ones in the $4\times 4$ matrix:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a_x & a_y & a_z & 1 \\
b_x-a_x & b_y-a_y & b_z-a_z & 0 \\
c_x-a_x & c_y-a_y & c_z-a_z & 0 \\
d_x-a_x & d_y-a_y & d_z-a_z & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
The $1$ in the upper right corner is on a "minus position" of the plus/minus-checkerboard we use for determinant calculation. Therefore this is
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a_x & a_y & a_z & 1 \\
b_x-a_x & b_y-a_y & b_z-a_z & 0 \\
c_x-a_x & c_y-a_y & c_z-a_z & 0 \\
d_x-a_x & d_y-a_y & d_z-a_z & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}
=
-\begin{vmatrix}
b_x-a_x & b_y-a_y & b_z-a_z \\
c_x-a_x & c_y-a_y & c_z-a_z \\
d_x-a_x & d_y-a_y & d_z-a_z
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Comment: In the original example, the fourth row is subtracted from the first three, which leaves a "+" in the bottom right corner. You are subtracting the first row from the next three and get a "-" in the upper right corner. These operations don't change the original 4x4 determinant, and they give the same result: The sign is opposite of what it should be by the given definition of the right-hand rule.